# Error in IDE (VScode) on a RxJS subscribe call with a typed parameter

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I'm trying out some RxJS functions in Angular and copied some code from a tutorial ([link](https://medium.com/@cpyle/rxjs-functions-part-1-3275c1cdde21)). My project is configured in 'strict' mode.
The app is simply logging the coordinates of a click in the console (I did a Stackblitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2mxngv?file=src/app/app.component.ts))

Both locally and on Stackblitz **the app works BUT locally my IDE is displaying an error**. On line 25 of AppComponent, within the `subscribe`, `onClick` is underlined and I get "`No overload matches this call`". The problem seems to be related to the type definition `MouseEvent` on line 12. If I change it to `any`, the error disappears.

My assumptions are:

1. the code works, because upon transpiling TS to JS, the typization is lost (so effectively it's like if I did have `any` in my final call)
2. Stackblitz does not show an error, because its constraints-checks are not as efficient as the ones from VScode

**My questions:**

- are my assumptions correct?
- how should I write my code in order NOT to get the IDE error? Should I use some kind of casting to 'any'? Wouldn't kind of beat the purpose of using 'strict' mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const eventListener = <K extends keyof DocumentEventMap>(type: K) => 
  bindCallback<K, DocumentEventMap[K]>(document.addEventListener)(type);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzxguu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You could also use `fromEvent` from rxjs instead:

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

...

fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(...);
```

Comment: mhm but the whole purpose of that example is to use "bindCallback". In order to use "fromEvent" I'd need to get rid of "bindCallback" as far as I can see (?)

Comment: thank you Mike, I'll try that later. And would you say my assumptions (especially the one on transpiling) are correct?

Comment: Hi again. I tried your snippet but I cannot really bring it to anything "working". Now I get an error directly on the 'subscribe'. I'm not sure I understand what it does. Maybe the code sample I took from Medium was not the best, I realize now that the article is 2 years old and things seem to have changed a bit.
I guess I'll look at some newer material to learn RxJS. Could you just tell me if my assumptions were correct? then I could accept your answer (ideally a working stackblitz or an explanation of what you did would also be cool, if that's not asking too much)

Comment: Apologies I made a typo, I am updating now and will add a stackblitz too

Comment: Your assumptions are essentially correct. The only thing is that the error checking is done by typescript, not VSCode/stackblitz so it is actually just that stackblitz has a less strict configuration of the tsconfig.json